# Generate Multiple PDF Page in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, pdf-generation

I need to embed Multiple Page PDF File with Email in my iOS App.

I can create Single PDF Page with this [this tutorial](http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/).

With above tutorials, I can only create single PDF Page.

I don't know how to create multiple Page?

Answer (score 1):

Creating multiple pages is the same as creating one page. For each page you call `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()` then you draw the content. The linked tutorial shows you this already in the `generatePdfWithFilePath:` method. You just need to change when the `done` variable is set so more than one page is generated.

Comment: So how can i check the end of one Page?

Comment: That's up to your content and how you draw it.

Comment: My contents is from UITextView and i still don't know how to create multiple page. please help.

Answer (score 1):

As rmaddy says, `uiGraphicsBeginPage` will create a page break. You have to decide the size of your page and when to begin new.

Work your way down the page, checking y value every step and when you reach max, begin new. Your page can be as long and as wide as you wish. You have to determine those parameters and keep track as you progress through your document.

Comment: My contents is from UITextView and I copied codes from above links. please help. I still don't know how to create it.

Comment: You are going to have be more specific. What have you been able to do? The tutorial seems fairly clear for its part. Have your tried to implement that? What do you need to do different. @rmaddy and my own answer point out how to start new page. We can't answer, not knowing what you are trying to print, how you are laying it out and what you are trying to achieve exactly.